# Removing the default guest user account on Android Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

How to remove the default Guest User on Android Lollipop in Nexus 5?

In the user settings, I am presented with option to add the guest user. However I am unable to remove the default guest user already present. I am able to remove the added guest users but not the default guest user. The phone is not rooted yet.

Answer (score 26):

Yeah, you can remove it. Just switch to the guest user, pull down the notification with two fingers and tap on the user icon in the top right corner. It will then offer you the possibility to remove the guest user.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Still the user is able to guest log from lock screen using add guest option

Comment: You should be able to disable that feature in the user options

Comment: that will delete an existing guest account, but not disable the feature of creating them in the first place. Yes, there's a checkbox to disable adding users (including guest) from the lock screen.

Comment: @RickyBeam See my answer: [Is there a way to remove guest in lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/119632)

Comment: @Ricky where is the check box to disable adding users from the lock screen? Please tell me.