# "App not installed" error

Tags: applications, installation, apk, amazon-appstore

I installed Badland from Play Store. It worked. Then I uninstalled it and tried installing it from Amazon Appstore. Every time I try to install it, I get the installing screen for about a minute (long time) and then the error "App not installed"

I found the apk file (from my filesystem, the one Amazon downloaded) and the exact same thing happens when I attempt to install it. I have redownloaded it many times.

I also have root and I'm running Android 5.1.1

EDIT: The message I get from terminal is: [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]

Comment: Can you confirm the info mentioned in first paragraph of the answer for [How to completely uninstall an app on Android Lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130) If yes, follow that same answer for the remedy.

Comment: There is a good chance the App from Amazon Playstore is unsigned - have you tried allowing 'Unknown Sources' in Security Settings ... why not just install it from Google playstore again?