# Access Android native settings manager

Tags: settings, lenovo

I got a Lenovo K3 Note with Android Lollipop 5.1, my problem with this phone is the hugely modified Android system. For example, there's no `Settings > Applications` or `Settings > More` menu in the Settings app.

How to restore the default Android settings manager so I can unlock these settings features?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, because that's the only Android settings that's available on your device, with current ROM. You might be interested in using custom AOSP ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Andrew's comment, Settings is a core system app that is tightly integrated into the ROM.  There is no way to replace it without flashing a custom ROM, and modifications like enabling or adding features would require building the Android source for your device.

If you are rooted or can use ADB, etc., there are a number of other ways to manage applications and settings — for example, [uninstalling apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130/1465).  Feel free to search the site and ask another question if you want to do something specific that hasn't already been covered.

Comment: I don't think that the settings app I have is from android, I think that lenovo have modified it, because I see that settings app is different from device to device while using the same version of android

Comment: @ERROPiX Yes they have modified it, but it is likely still the same package -- com.android.settings.  You should be able to verify this by watching logcat when you launch it.

Comment: I have flashed the official rom and the problem is fixed, so I think the DX shop modify the rom to put some ads etc