# Deleting apps from android phone that can't sign in

Tags: applications, settings

We have an old android phone that grandchildren use for play.  No SIM card, but on wifi.  The Google account previously used is obsolete, so we can't sign in.  But without signing in, the "play store" won't let us get to the list of apps to delete them.

We'd like to delete Contacts and the contact list, Phone and the list of calls and transcribed voicemails, and other things like that.

If we reset to factory settings, all the games disappear too, and we'd have to log in to a valid account to get them back.

And, I cannot find the settings! (Also want to turn off the unneeded cell radio to save battery.

Comment: Deleting an app doesn't need Play Store, but there's always a possibility that the Contacts and Phone apps are system apps, which you can't uninstall without root access. You can try [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130) if it's possible, but you probably need [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851) instead...

Comment: I’d rather not root it, for the risk that an experimenting child will inadvertently trash the whole thing.  So I’ll post a different question.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217350/delete-personal-data-from-phone-that-cant-sign-in-to-google

Comment: There should be no need for Play Store, as I answered in your duplicate questions. You can use Settings-Apps to remove or disable most apps, and if you need to disable system applications that are not accessible here, you can do it via ADB without root. Google would be your friend here...

Comment: Since the ‘settings’ can’t be found, that doesn’t help. And it was not a duplicate; it was a different question.  And Google (NSA’s biggest competitor) is never my friend.