# Android 12: App gets installed for multiple users, even though I disabled multiple users in settings

Tags: applications, installation, multi-user, android-12

I enabled multiple users in Settings -> System -> Multiple users, but later I disabled it. Now, when I install an app with Android Studio, it gets installed to multiple users, and I can only fully delete the app by going to Settings -> Apps, and uninstall app for all users.

Is there any other place I need to disable multiple users?

Comment: I have an answer for [the same issue on an older Android version](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130/44325), including deactivating the "guest account", though not sure if Android 12 still has it or not.

Comment: Can you list exact model of the phone (since i'm not sure if you are referring to android's multi user or second space of the phone's OS) Also what do you mean by "I disabled multi users" and "it gets installed to multi user"

Comment: Its a Pixel 3 :)  44yu5h that is whats happening. First, I enabled multiple users, then I disabled the feature. Yet, apps still ask if I want to uninstall for all users...

Comment: Hmm, did you add a new user after enabling it? If so, did you remove the user before disabling it?

Comment: Can you attach a few images of how things look like on your device? I'm having trouble following. I tried replicating that but couldn't. I installed the android app from Android Studio (i believe that's what you too are doing) and it just got installed only on my main user without any issue. It only gets installed on the second user when I've uninstalled the app from the main user and switched to the second user (as it should be). But in no circumstances the app is/should be installed on both the users since the filesystem of users are meant to be separate. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruycll.jpg

Comment: @AndrewT. 's linked answer seems to be the same , so probably we can close this question https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130/44325