# Is there a way to remove the account icon on Android M?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have completely removed the Guest account by following this method:
[Is there a way to remove the Guest account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/102821/)

I've disabled & removed the guest, then added the two build.prop fw.* entries but I can't even find settings.db and the adb shell settings global guest_user_enabled 0 cmd has no effect.

I still see the guest account icon when I pull down the top bar and click the blue user thing pulls up a blank name card.

Is there a way to completely remove this icon?

Comment: Sounds like you actually have disabled the Guest account if that icon is now functioning purely as a contact shortcut, so I've rephrased the question.