# How configure more than 5 multi-users

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, multi-user, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Tab3 10 running Android M. It allows to configure multiple users but no more than 5 (including guest user).

**Is there a way how to enhance the limit to configure more users?**

5 multiple users could be enough for me but the 5th one is reserved to guest user. I've tried to [*disable guest user feature*](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119632/202469) with no effect. There is still guest user that allocates 1 of 5 multi-user slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of users is defined in a resource overlay defined by device manufacturer. The resource is named config_multiuserMaximumUsers. Check in [Device Administration doc: Multi User](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html). This is manageable via APIs.

Comment: Does it mean I'm able to change it to for example to 6 without rooting the phone?

Comment: Nop ! Not immediatly at least. In order to change such config values, you need to be root, actually you should even need to rebuild the firmware because a resource overlay is a build object that will modify several underlying resources in the firmware (not sure how exactly for the multi-user feature). It should be possible to change it at runtime, I didn't yet had a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your build.prop file using the build.prop app or root browser and add the following at the bottom:

```
fw.max_users=9001
```

Change 9001 to as many users you want to have support for.