# How to disable the guest feature WITHOUT having to be the only user

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-6, multi-user

How can I disable the guest acount feature on my samsung galaxy s6 WITHOUT having to delete all users (other than me, the owner) or disabling the multiuser feature completely. I want to have users other than me, but I don't want the guest account. My device **is rooted**.

I found [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102821/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-guest-account/119632) other question. This question is **not a dupe** because the answers to the other question do not say how to do it without requiring myself to be the only user.

(My android version is 5.0.2, and my goal is to prevent anyone with physical access from being able to log in using this guest feature, and I don't want to encrypt my device or install custom recovery)

Comment: I didnt ever tried to make a multi-user phone, but did you tried making a new user and then delete the guest (that would not remove the multi-user system)?

Comment: @TheAnonDevil there is no option presented in the settings to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works for me on Android 5.0.1 and 5.1.1

Open a terminal, grant it root access then run

```
settings put global guest_user_enabled 0
```

You don't need to add `fw.max_users=1` to your `build.prop`. It prevents more accounts from being created besides disabling guest feature. The above method only shuts off guest while leaving the "more users" option available.

---

Alternatively, if you don't need dynamically creating & deleting extra users, you can create a few before proceeding.

Add this line to your `build.prop`.

```
fw.max_users=2
```

The multi-user settings will stil be available from your Settings app, but a guest (or any extra account) is kept from being created.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run :

```
adb shell settings put secure guest_user_enabled 0
adb shell settings put global guest_user_enabled 0
adb shell settings put system guest_user_enabled 0
```

I did not have to root my device, just use ADB platform-utility. Installation explanation is [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/).

I am under Android 9

Comment: Executing `adb shell settings put global guest_user_enabled 0` was enough on my Android 9 tablet (Alldocube iPlay 10 Pro) to remove Guest account from the list of users.