# Remove/disable guest account on Android 6.0.1, but still allow restricted accounts?

Tags: samsung, tablet, multi-user

I've been researching this exact issue and am aware of these 2 Q&A's on this site:

- [Is there a way to remove the Guest account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102821/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-guest-account)
- [Removing the default guest user account on Android Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87664/removing-the-default-guest-user-account-on-android-lollipop?s=4|1.3014)

Neither of these either cover what I'm asking or are wrong (the 2nd one mentions how to delete the guest account, but it continues to be shown if you switch back to the main account, for example).

I'd like to disable the guest account completely and still retain the ability to have multiple restricted accounts on my Samsung Tab A (model GM-T350).

We purchased these for our kids and find the lack of security to restrict them disturbing. I have a Nexus 7 tablet and am able to restrict access to restricted accounts there without issue, however on the Samsung version of Android this has proved challenging.

The method using the `adb shell` to set guest_user_enabled to 0 but this appears to only work if you have no other accounts, besides the administrator account, so that simply won't work.

Putting a password on the guest account will not work either, since you're able to simply "Start Over" and wipe the account and install whatever apps you like.

Deleting the Guest account will get rid of it, however if you slide the top level pulldown and switch to the administrator account, and then hit the power button and slide it down again you'll see the Guest icon show back up and you can simply start a new instance of the Guest account.

Worse still, when doing this same thing you'll be presented with a "Add User" button which blows my mind, since why would I want anyone to simply start making accounts on my device.

[image: ss01]

**NOTE:** The below reference is the best overview I've found thus far around parental controls in Android, but many of the screenshots are from non-Samsung variants, best I can tell.

#### References

- [What are Android’s inbuilt parental controls?](https://screentimelabs.com/android-user-profiles/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a restricted account named Guest
2. Sign into that account
3. Go back to administrator account
4. Delete the account that you made in step one

You can still access the Guest user in the user section of the settings menu but not from the lock screen. This works for me. I hope it works for you too.

As for the add user button that can be disabled by going
Settings>Users>...>Add users when the device is locked